# how to stop the Qtimer upon a condition

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

when i executing this Qtimer it says "invalid use of 'this' in non-member function"

```
QTimer *timerStart( )
{
QTimer* timer = new QTimer(  );
Ball *b = new Ball();

QObject::connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),b,SLOT(move()));
//timer->start( timeMillisecond );
timer->start(15);
return timer;
}
```

my ball.h file

```
class Ball: public QObject, public QGraphicsRectItem{
Q_OBJECT
public:
// constructors
Ball(QGraphicsItem* parent=NULL);

// public methods
double getCenterX();




public slots:
// public slots
void move();



private:
// private attributes
double xVelocity;
double yVelocity;
int counter = 0;
QTimer timerStart( );



// private methods
void stop();
void resetState();
void reverseVelocityIfOutOfBounds();
void handlePaddleCollision();
void handleBlockCollision();
};

#endif // BALL_H
```

the move() function is in the same class. what i want to do is stop the returned timer upon a if condition is satisfied.

when i issue this code in Ball::Ball constructor in Cpp it works fine. the ball is moving.

```
  QTimer* timer = new QTimer();
  timer->setInterval(4000);

  connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(move()));

  timer->start(15);
```

but when i add Qtimer *timerStart beyond the Ball::Ball constructor, iT doesnt work

Comment: I think your missing the function scope in your class. `QTimer * YourClass::timerStart(..)`, add this function to your class h file.

Comment: sir i tried but that gives me an error,

Comment: please share more code, so I can help you.

Comment: sir i have updated the code.

Comment: `timer` is visible only within the constructor. If you want to access it elsewhere, declare it as a class member.

Comment: Sir its a great help if you can give me an example how to declare it as a class member to return the timer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the QTimer as a member in you class

h file:

```
class Ball: public QObject, public QGraphicsRectItem{
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    // constructor
    Ball(QGraphicsItem* parent=Q_NULLPTR);
    // control your timer
    void start();
    void stop();
    ...
  private:
    QTimer * m_poTimer;
}
```

Initiate the timer object in your constractor

cpp file:

```
Ball::Ball(QGraphicsItem* parent) :
      QGraphicsItem(parent)
{  
  m_poTimer = new QTimer(this); // add this as a parent to control the timer resource
  m_poTimer->setInterval(4000);

  connect(m_poTimer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(move()));
}

void Ball::start()
{
   // start timer
   m_poTimer->start();
}

void Ball::stop()
{
   // stop timer
   m_poTimer->stop();
}
```

Comment: thank you sir, this really helped me. you save my day sir

Comment: @AlexDRex great, glad I helped you :)